# Rails data-disable-with equivalent in HTML5/JS/Vue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, vue.js

I've been developing on rails in the past and have been using the `data-disable-with` attribute on buttons for disabling on certain click actions. Is there an out of box solution like this in JS or in native HTML5. I'm developing in VueJS so any Vue specific solution will be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

With VueJs:

```
data() {
  return {
    disabled: false
  }
}
```

```
 <button @click="submit" :disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
```

```
methods: {
  submit() {
    this.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this isn't exactly what data-disable-with does. Moreover, I was looking at re-using something available as it's a very typical problem and should have an existing pattern.